# host access to web application on virtual using iis express

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, iis-express

I created a web application in my virtual pc using the latest and greatest web matrix items (including IIS Express) on an XP SP3 virtual.

Is it possible to access that application from my host machine?

I know I can install IIS 5.1 on my XP virtual and access my web application remotely (from Host) but what if I don't have IIS installed and have IIS Express installed instead?

Comment: Yes it is possible, if I remeber well, you select on the Adapter, the Shared networking (NAT) and the virtual pc gets an ip address that you can use on your pc to access it. Other way is to use as adapter the same adapter as your computer, and your computer is connected to a router to the internet, then you access the virtual pc with this new ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at following links

http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

http://forums.iis.net/t/1175028.aspx